# How to use elasticsearch painless BigDecimal in java code?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I use painless to update doc. how to use BigDecimal to finish it ? Using Elasticsearch 6.8.1.
[Script JavaDoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.8.10/org/elasticsearch/script/Script.html)
Script construtor is:

```
public Script (ScriptType type,
              java.lang.String lang,
              java.lang.String idOrCode,
              java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> params)
```

My Code is:

```
StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("poundageRate", poundageRate.doubleValue());
script.append("ctx._source.poundage=ctx._source.amount*params.poundageRate;");
Script scriptObj = new Script(INLINE, DEFAULT_SCRIPT_LANG, script.toString(), params);
```

My Question is:
How to let ctx._source.amount*params.poundageRate using BigDecimal method
multiply and setScale

```
new BigDecimal("ctx._source.amount").multiply(new BigDecimal("params.poundageRate")).setScale(2, HALF_UP).stripTrailingZeros()
```

Thanks a lot i will appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigDecimal is definitely [supported](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/6.8/painless-api-reference.html) by Painless in ES 6.8.

You should let the `poundageRate` parameter as a string instead of transforming it to a double value.

```
params.put("poundageRate", poundageRate.toString());
```

Then, your script can contain the code you're showing (with slight modifications), i.e.

```
ctx._source.amount = new BigDecimal(ctx._source.amount).multiply(new BigDecimal(params.poundageRate)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).stripTrailingZeros()
```

Try it out, it works well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. but es happen error. printstack is:Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.NotSerializableExceptionWrapper: class_cast_exception: Cannot cast java.lang.Double to java.lang.String
at org.elasticsearch.painless.PainlessScript$Script.execute(ctx._source.payFrom=params.payFrom;ctx._source.finishTime=params.finishTime;ctx._source.userId=params.userId;ctx._source.status=params.status;ctx._source.poundage=new BigDecimal(ctx._source.amount).multiply(new BigDecimal(params.poundageRate)).setScale(2,  ...:190) BigDecimal(ctx._source.amount).multiply(new

Comment: I think it's because you store `amount` as a native double instead of a stringified double (which allows you to keep the precision)... if that's the case, then you simply need to do `new BigDecimal(ctx._source.amount.toString())`

Comment: It works！ Thank you very much for solving my problem.  Merry Christmas~